# How to add nested rows in AG-Grid row groups (Angular)

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have the data set as given below for an AGGrid table .

Data -.

```
[{
    "name": "Test A",
    "id": 10,
    "desc": "test description",
    "status": "Valid",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Test Child A-1",
            "id": 100,
            "desc": "test description",
            "status": "Invalid"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test Child A-2",
            "id": 88,
            "desc": "test description",
            "status": "Valid"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Test B",
    "id": 68,
    "desc": "test description",
    "status": "Valid",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Test Child B-1",
            "id": 45,
            "desc": "test description",
            "status": "Valid"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test Child B-1",
            "id": 35,
            "desc": "test description",
            "status": "Valid"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to have nested grouping on this which has the 1st level grouping as the main outer items i,e - 'Test A' and 'Test B'. And sub groups on those which has the children data on row level grouping.

On opening group 'Test A' , i should see the children items with the same col defs.
Using Angular AGGrid for the same

Please suggest a way to try this. Using AGGrid enterprise version for this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using [master-detail feature](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail/) of AG-Grid

```
const gridOptions = {
// enable Master / Detail
masterDetail: true,

// the first Column is configured to use agGroupCellRenderer
columnDefs: [
     { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
     { field: 'account' }
 ],

// provide Detail Cell Renderer Params
detailCellRendererParams: {
     // provide the Grid Options to use on the Detail Grid
     detailGridOptions: {
         columnDefs: [
             { field: 'callId' },
             { field: 'direction' },
             { field: 'number'}
         ]
     },
     // get the rows for each Detail Grid
     getDetailRowData: params => {
         params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
     }
 },

// other grid options ...
```

}

Comment: What I need is more of this example https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tree-data/#supplying-tree-data